# Binding Mutiline of text column to HTML with html tags

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint-online

I have a sharePoint column of type MultiLine Text that which enhanced rich text. When i get the data from server some external tags will apend. when i tried to append it to HTML using react the tags also binding as a text.

Below is the text that appended to HTML.
[image: HTML that appended]

The HTML tags should not bind as text. They should append as HTML tags only with including text. Please help me out in this.
Code i used for this:

[image: Code i used]

Comment: You can use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to just copy paste the text as html : https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Comment: if you are looking for exact snippet:
`<p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: item.Description}}></p>`
...
`<p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: item.Answer}}></p>`